# Embedded script not showing in preview popup in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, github

I have some JavaScript that will POST to a new window in order to show me a preview of the content that I'm working.  Here is basically what I'm doing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#previewButton").click(function () {
        $("#previewform").remove();

        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("id", "previewform");
        form.setAttribute("method", "post");
        form.setAttribute("action", "/Home/Preview");
        form.setAttribute("target", "formresult");

        var bodyField = document.createElement("input");
        bodyField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        bodyField.setAttribute("name", "Body");
        bodyField.setAttribute("value", $("#Body").val());
        var nameField = document.createElement("input");
        nameField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        nameField.setAttribute("name", "Slug");
        nameField.setAttribute("value", $("#Slug").val());
        var titleField = document.createElement("input");
        titleField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        titleField.setAttribute("name", "Title");
        titleField.setAttribute("value", $("#Title").val());
        form.appendChild(bodyField);
        form.appendChild(nameField);
        form.appendChild(titleField);
        document.body.appendChild(form);

        window.open("/Home/Preview", 'formresult', 'scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes');

        form.submit();
    });
});
```

This works fine.  A strange thing that I noticed though, is that when I put some embedded gists into the content, those don't show up in Chrome.  They do show up in IE though.

Is this a Chrome bug (or feature), or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Chrome and almost every browser has popup blocker. Disable it and try again.

Comment: No, the popup appears just fine, it's just that the script tags in the body don't render in the popup.  Everything else renders fine.

Comment: Do you have a link to the page in that case? Btw, if you are using jQuery, why do you need that long way of elements creation? All these attributes and elements can be set in a more simple way with the help of jQuery.

Comment: I couldn't give you a link because a) it's behind authentication and b) it's a POST operation anyway

Comment: What about saved version of html code? I tried this code and it opened a new window without any problem. So the problem seats somewhere else.

Comment: The window is popping up just fine, and mostly it works fine. But if I have a Gist (which is embedded javascript) in the preview content, then that Gist doesn't show up in the preview.

Comment: Did you check at /home/preview that you've got the data you need? I do not see any problem with the quoted script. Did you check error console of the browser? Also check 'network' tab in developer tools of Chrome for the data submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Try it in much shorter form (I've moved id separately to compact the listing) :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#previewButton").click(function () {
        $("#previewform").remove();
        window.open("/Home/Preview", 'formresult',
                     'scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,height=600,width=800');
        $("<form method='post' action='/Home/Preview' target='formresult'/>")
         .attr('id', 'previewform')
         .append($("<input type='hidden' name='Body'/>").val($("#Body").val()))
         .append($("<input type='hidden' name='Slug'/>").val($("#Slug").val()))
         .append($("<input type='hidden' name='Title'/>").val($("#Title").val()))
         .appendTo('body')
         .submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: I appreciate this much more readable and compact version, but it's still doing the same thing.